# React-Native - Navigate back to pushed pages

Tags: react-native

I am pushing the same page multiple times and would like to navigate back to a particular instance.

Initially on a button click from home page

```
this.props.navigation.push('Page', {name: 'first', ..});
```

Then from above page to

```
this.props.navigation.push('Page', {name: 'second', ..});
```

Similarly from second

```
this.props.navigation.push('Page', {name: 'third', ..});
```

I need thee buttons in third page to

```
<Button onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.goBack()}> go back to second </Button>
<Button> go back to first </Button>
```

What should I do on onPress of the other button to go back to first page?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are the StackNavigator, you can try using the `reset` parameter.
So your Buttons onPress method should look something like this:

```
<Button onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.reset()}> go back to first</Button>
<Button> go back to first</Button>
```

But Say you have 4 screens and you are on the 4th screen and you wish to go to the 2nd not the first screen, the reset method will always clear the stack navigation so it would take you to the first screen.
To achieve this you can use the `key` parameter with the `goBack()` method, for more details check the docs [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#goback-close-the-active-screen-and-move-back).

Hope this Helps!